# Modify XML RSS Feed for Windows 8 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, windows-8, rss

Currently making a Windows 8 RSS reader app for a specific site. Everything is working except for video [usually YouTube] since the website uses `<object></object>` to embed videos rather than `<iframe>`. the result is just a large  blank object block where ever the video should be.

My first instinct was to find and replace the `<object></object>` tags with `<iframe>` and add the src attribute with the proper URL. I created a dummy app to test if this method would work, and the solution worked, if all you were changing was static HTML.

Dummy App Code:

```
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <object width="853" height="480" id="test">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/2rDs7W3WRIk?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/2rDs7W3WRIk?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="853" height="480" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
    </object></div>
```

Wrote and called the below function, which does indeed work. Want to do something similar to the XML document:

```
 function setHTML5video() {
    var listOfSrcs = document.getElementsByTagName("embed");
    for (var i = 0; i < listOfSrcs.length; i += 1) {
        var videoSrc = document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[i].getAttribute("src");
        var newSrc = videoSrc.replace("/v/", "/embed/");            
        //var newNode = '<iframe width="853" height="480" src="' + newSrc + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'; 
        var iFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
        iFrame.setAttribute("src", newSrc);
        document.getElementsByTagName("object")[i].replaceNode(iFrame);
        //WinJS.Utilities.setOuterHTMLUnsafe(test, newNode);
    }
}
```

End of Dummy App Code.

However, due to lack of knowledge of the Windows 8 API and despite searching all day for the answer online, I cannot find how to do the same to an XML feed that is being downloaded from an external site. I am probably missing something fundamental.

```
function itemInvoked(z) {
        var currentArticle = articlesList.getAt(z.detail.itemIndex);                       
        WinJS.Utilities.setInnerHTMLUnsafe(articlecontent, currentArticle.content);
        articlelist.style.display = "none";
        articlecontent.style.display = "";
        mainTitle.innerHTML = currentArticle.title;             
        WinJS.UI.Animation.enterPage(articlecontent);        
    }
```

When the user clicks on a thumbnail, the XML RSS feed for that corresponding article is pulled up and injected into the  with the id = "articlecontent". I want to modify that feed prior to injecting it.

```
<section id="content">
    <div id="articlelist" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
         data-win-options="{ itemDataSource: mmoNewsPosts.ItemList.dataSource, itemTemplate: MMOItemTemplate }"></div> 
        <!-- Article Content -->       
    <div id="articlecontent"></div>        
        <!-- Article Content -->        
</section>
```

Edit, because there appears to be confusion, I already have the feed loaded in via WinJS.xhr:

```
 function downloadMMOFeed(FeedUrl) {
  WinJS.xhr({ url: FeedUrl, responseType: "xml" }).then(function (rss) {
      pageTitle = rss.responseXML.querySelector("title").textContent;
      mainTitle.innerHTML = pageTitle;
      var items = rss.responseXML.querySelectorAll("item");
//more stuff...
for (var n = 0; n < items.length; n +=1) {
article.content = items[n].querySelector("description").textContent;
//more stuff...
```

Comment: Think I found a solution; will post an update tomorrow when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just load the XML feed in by XHR and then parse the result before binding it to the page? For Example:

```
    WinJS.xhr({
    url: "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml", responseType: "xml"
})
    .done(
        function (request) {
            var text = request.responseText;
            //TODO : Parse the XML returned by the server which is in var text

        });
```

In Windows 8 there is no cross domain restriction so something like this is entirely possible.

Comment: Already have a very similar function located elsewhere in the main JS file that uses WinJS.xhr.